# Cannot ping to my router even though wifi is working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04.  I have been unable to ping to my default local gateway, much less connect to the internet since my installation.

Below is my output to ifconfig:

Output of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:b9:e2:3d:20 
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e9600000-e9620000 
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1362 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:142670 (142.6 KB)  TX bytes:142670 (142.6 KB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:27:10:0c:9b:50  
          inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::227:10ff:fe0c:9b50/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:463 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1234 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:146587 (146.5 KB)  TX bytes:86383 (86.3 KB
```

Below is my output to /etc/network/interfaces

```
/etc/network/interfaces:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Below is my output to cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 75.75.75.75
nameserver 75.75.76.76
search hsd1.il.comcast.net
```

Below is the contents of /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Below is my output to: nmcli dev list iface wlan0 | grep IP4:

```
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.1.103/24, gw = 192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             75.75.75.75
IP4.DNS[2]:                             75.75.76.76
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          hsd1.il.comcast.net.
```

output of route -n:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0 wlan0
```

I have verified that /etc/resolv.conf is properly symlinked to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

When I ping to my local gateway, the result is this:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.103 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I can ping to localhost, 127.0.0.1, and 192.168.1.103 (my IP address) just fine.

Comment: You seem to be using wlan0. Is that desired? Have you tried switching to wired to see if the problem isn't the wireless router?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex!  I can connect to the internet just fine on other computers using the same wireless router.  Currently, I don't have any ethernet cables on me.  My iptables is configured to accept anything.  Have you had any experiences in which computers running Windows can connect to the internet via a wireless router whereas those running Ubuntu 12.04 cannot?

Comment: I had back in Ubuntu 9.5 or something like that. At the time I had to use a wrapper (namely ndiswrapper) to install a XP wireless driver, but I have no idea if that's the issue you are having. I **guess** it could be a defective or incompatible driver - since you upgraded that is a possibility. If you know your way try messing around with it, otherwise wait for an answer or try the [IRC help channel](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat).

Comment: So I didn't actually upgrade to 12.04.  I have a current version of Ubuntu 11.10 installed on the same machine as a loop mount (I think this is the correct term, but I'm not sure.  I used a Windows installer to obtain this configuration).  When I use my version of 11.10, I can connect to the internet just fine.  To install 12.04, I freed some memory previously allocated to Windows and I downloaded the iso files to a usb.